# perl web development get local file size

Tags: perl, cgi

My hosting is not allowed to upload big files to server with PHP. So I need to upload with Perl.

I need to display uploaded file size. And here is my part of code:

```
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";
binmode UPLOADFILE;

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
{
print UPLOADFILE;
}

close UPLOADFILE;

$filename = ">$upload_dir/$filename";

use File::stat;
my $stat = stat($filename);
say $stat->size;
 
say stat($filename)->size;
```

But I got an error:

> Can't call method "size" on an undefined value at upload.cgi line 56.

#### Update

After Borodin's answer I updated to this new code, which is now giving an *Internal server error*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;
use diagnostics;
use File::stat;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
... #SOME CODES ##
my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo");

open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";
binmode UPLOADFILE;

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
{
print UPLOADFILE;
}

close UPLOADFILE;

my $full_name = "$upload_dir/$filename";

{
    open my $up_fh, '>:raw', $full_name or die qq{Unable to open "$full_name" for output: $!};

    print $up_fh, $_ while <$upload_filehandle>;
}

printf "%.2fMB uploaded\n", (-s $full_name) / (1024 * 1024);



print $query->header ( );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `$filename` is set to `>$upload_dir/$filename` which is wrong. The `>` is the mode for the `open` call and isn't part of the file name

You want

```
my $filename = "$upload_dir/$filename";
```

Also, rather than using `File::stat` etc. you can just use the `-s` file test operator

```
say -s $filename;
```

which is much more concise

I would code the whole thing like this

```
my $full_name = "$upload_dir/$filename";

{
    open my $up_fh, '>:raw', $full_name or die qq{Unable to open "$full_name" for output: $!};

    print $up_fh, $_ while <$upload_filehandle>;
}

printf "%.2fMB uploaded\n", (-s $full_name) / (1024 * 1024);
```

#### Update

You're misunderstanding what my code does. You're opening the upload file *twice* now -- mine replaces all of that. It should look like this below

The reason you're getting the error is that you're printing the file size before the HTTP header. I don't know what you want your response to look like, but you probably want to wrap it in HTML and print it *after* `$query->header()`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;

#... SOME CODE

my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload('photo');

my $full_name = "$upload_dir/$filename";

{
    open my $uploaded_fh, '>:raw', $full_name or die qq{Unable to open "$full_name" for output: $!};

    print $uploaded_fh $_ while <$upload_filehandle>;
}

my $size = -s $full_name;

print $query->header('text/plain');

printf "\n%dB file uploaded\n", $size;
```

Comment: @AykhanAmiraslanli: You'll have to show your new code. It sounds like you have a syntax error

Comment: @AykhanAmiraslanli:  Okay I've explained more in my solution. By the way you should always *add* to the information in your question. Never delete anything, otherwise comments and solutions that relate to the older stuff may no longer make sense. I've combined your old and new posts for you

Comment: Yes I am new on this site :) thanks for doing it for me. But I couldn't solve my problem on my perl code

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: @AykhanAmiraslanli: I had an extra comma that shouldn't be there. Please copy my code again